# Proving two propositions are equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

Let $X \subset \mathbb R$, $K$ be a compact subspace of $X$ and $f: K\to \mathbb R$. And let $\alpha>0.$

Consider these two propositions.

$$(A) \quad \exists C> 0\ ;\   x,y\in K \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|\leqq C|x-y|^\alpha $$

$$(B) \quad \forall a\in K,\exists C>0, \exists \delta>0 \ ; \  | x|<\delta \Rightarrow  |f(a+x)-f(a)|\leqq C|x|^\alpha　$$

I want to prove propositions $(A)$ and $(B)$ are equivalent.

I did $(A) \Rightarrow (B)$, but I'm having difficulty in $(B) \Rightarrow (A)$.

---

Suppose $(B)$ holds and $(A)$ doesn't hold.

Then, for all $n\in \mathbb N,$ there exists $x_n, y_n \in K$ s.t. $$|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|>n|x_n-y_n|^\alpha \cdots (\ast)$$

Since $K$ is compact, I can assume $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ converge to $x,y\in K$ respectively.

If $x\neq y,$ then let $n\to \infty$ in $(\ast),$ I get $|f(x)-f(y)|=\infty (\because f \mathrm{\ is \ continuous\  since\ } (B))$.Can I deduce a contradiction from here ?

And if $x=y$, I don't know how I can deduce a contradiction.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

$$|x| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x+a) - f(a)| \leq C|x|^\alpha$$

In particular it must hold true for $x\rightarrow x-y$ and $a = y$

$$|x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x-y+y) - f(y)| = |f(x) - f(y)| \leq C|x-y|^\alpha$$

Comment: What contradiction is there ? @Gupta